# jquery animation not wanting to fire

Tags: jquery, html

What the heck am I doing work I can't seem to get the animation to fire. I think it's got something to do with the why in which I'm trying to call the jquery animation

```
<script>
$('#grid').click(function() {
   console.log("dsdsd");
   $('#book').animate({
       opacity: 0.25,
       left: '+=50',
       height: 'toggle'
     }, 5000, function() {
   });
});
</script>
```

```
</head><body>

  <div class="portfolio">
    <ul id="grid">
       <li><a href="#" id="book" ><img src="1.jpg"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="2.jpg"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="3.jpg"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="4.jpg"></a></li>

   </ul></div>
```

Comment: Try wrapping your code in a DOM ready statement -- `$(document).ready(function() { //your code in here! });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a slow animation, but it works (http://jsfiddle.net/sXyBa/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#grid').click(function() {
     console.log("dsdsd");
     $('#book').animate({
       opacity: 0.25,
       left: '+=50',
       height: 'toggle'
       }, 5000, function() {
    });
  }); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you're missing:

```
jQuery(function($){

   // your code here

});
```

Which will make sure the DOM is read before you start to interact with your elements and events.

P.S: the above is a nicer shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){`

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

More: you have an unneeded callback `animate()` function which should look like:

```
$('#book').animate({
   opacity: 0.25,
   left: '+=50',
   height: 'toggle'
}, 5000);
```

unless you have some crazy things in there which will be triggered once that animation is over